# Regex pattern does not work properly.. but only in Extjs / Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, extjs3

I've built a regex pattern to check the strength of passwords:

```
(?=^.{8,15}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

It forces the user to use a password which characters originate from at least 3 of the 4 following categories:

> 1. at least 1 upper case character
> 2. at least 1 lower case character
> 3. at least 1 numerical character
> 4. at least 1 special character / symbol
>
> Note: It also enforces a min and max length {8,15}

The pattern works fine on a server side PHP script and I've also tested it with multiple javascript Regex-tester-tools (e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). Everything looks perfect so far...

**BUT**, if I'm using it inside of a simple *Extjs textfield validator*, the validator only returns TRUE, if I'm using all 4 categories.

```
validator: function (value) {

        var pattern = 
            '(?=^.{8,15}$)'+
            '((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|' + 
            '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|' +
            '(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|' +
            '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*';
        if (value.match(pattern)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return this.i18n.invalidPassword;
        }
    }
```

And now, I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Comment: password validators like this are a real nightmare for people who use secure random password generators. Also, why such a low maximum length? Surely the passwords are being stored hashed anyway; what difference does it make if they're longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting up the pattern incorrectly:

```
    var pattern = new RegExp(
        '(?=^.{8,15}$)'+
        '((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|' + 
        '(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|' +
        '(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|' +
        '(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*'
    );
```

Note the `\\` instead of `\`.  If you don't do that, the `\` will be gone by the time the regular expression code gets to it. You could alternatively use native regex syntax, but there's no way to break that up across multiple lines.

*edit* — specifically, the `\\` before the `\d` occurrences in your regex.  If you don't double the backslash, then the regular expression will just see a lower-case "d".

Comment: No, you don't need to use RegExp... and by the way, it doesn't change anything. but thanks for the reply

Comment: @derphil well *something* has to parse the string as a regular expression, and the key is that if you don't double the backslash characters it won't work.

Comment: @Pointy You've forgot to remove the semicolon.

Comment: @Pointy: Thx! The \\ was the perfect hint